# Why is there no model definition in the codebase but a table in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, activerecord

I have been trying to figure out why I cannot find a model in my code even though the table is in the database.  The table is a cross reference table from a many to many relationship.  Does active record handle this specially?  The table only contains two foreign keys and audit fields.  The reason I am getting even more confused is because we have other cross reference tables that I can see the model for.

Comment: Edit:  This is a ruby on rails environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the [has_and_belongs_to_many association here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

This will not require a model but will require an entry in the migrations which you should check.

Excerpt from link, example models:

```
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
end
```

example migrations:

```
class CreateAssembliesAndParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assemblies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :parts do |t|
      t.string :part_number
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :assemblies_parts, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :assembly
      t.belongs_to :part
    end
  end
end
```